# scrollreveal javascript not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have this code ...

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal({ reset: true });

    sr.reveal('.whitecircle, .circleStatsItemBox, .circleStat', { duration: 200 });
function circle_progess() {

    var divElement = $('div'); //log all div elements

    if (retina()) {

        $(".whiteCircle").knob({
            'min':0,
            'max':100,
            'readOnly': true,
            'width': 240,
            'height': 240,
            'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
            'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
            'dynamicDraw': true,
            'thickness': 0.2,
            'tickColorizeValues': true
        });

        $(".circleStat").css('zoom',0.5);
        $(".whiteCircle").css('zoom',0.999);


    } else {

        $(".whiteCircle").knob({
            'min':0,
            'max':100,
            'readOnly': true,
            'width': 120,
            'height': 120,
            'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
            'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
            'dynamicDraw': true,
            'thickness': 0.2,
            'tickColorizeValues': true
        });

    }



        $(".circleStatsItemBox").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).find(".count > .number").html();
  var unit = $(this).find(".value > .unit").html();
  var percent = $(this).find("input").val() / 100;

  countSpeed = 2300 * percent;
  endValue = value;

  $(this).find(".count > .unit").html(unit);
  $(this).find(".count > .number").countTo({
    from: 0,
    to: endValue,
    speed: countSpeed,
    refreshInterval: 50
  });

  //$(this).find(".count").html(value*percent + unit);
});

}
```

and i want to use the reveal scroll js from this link, have followed the documentation and inserted the code in the html just before body and have pasted this javascript onto the section just above the top of the code above.

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal({ reset: true });

sr.reveal('.whitecircle, .circleStatsItemBox, .circleStat', { duration: 200 });
```

it says ScrollReveal is not defined and unsure how to proceed.  Any help would be very grateful for.

the console message ....

```
22:13:52.842 ReferenceError: ScrollReveal is not defined
<anonymous>custom.js:702
1custom.js:702:1
```

this js file is referenced in the html page i am targeting for this code ..

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@3.3.2/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end: JavaScript-->

</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) Are you putting your code before or after the section where you add the reveal scroll script?

Comment: yes in my description that was actually the console message which was as above , i just pasted it in an edit .... the code is just above the main functions

Comment: Basically, the "ReferenceError" message means that the function you want to use just ain't there. In this instance, your code has no function called `ScrollReveal` that takes an object as a parameter. You mention something about a link and you maybe inserted this, but we can't see that. Take a look at [mcve] for more information on what we'd like to see in a question about an error.

Comment: so it says to ref the source just before the body tag end ... so i put this into the html page ... <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@3.3.2/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok so I got it working , but need it to just run the code as you scroll down the page and see more of the same elements ... is this a new question ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I got it working , basically the call of the javascript file url in question needed to be above the other js files including the custom js file where the above code comes from